# greendao no such table

Tags: android, greendao

I get this error no such table: MEAL (code 1) in the code generated by greendao.

In class i have

```
@Entity
public class Meal {}
```

and in generated class

```
public static final String TABLENAME = "MEAL";
```

I mention that others class/tables are working and also is the new version of greenDao in which is no need of daoMaster and it is working just with annotations.
I cleaned and rebuild, but without succcess. Any ideas?

Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling this: `MealDao.createTable(daoSession.getDatabase(), false);`

Answer (score 0):

If you face this situation, probably you need to add migrations for your db. Here is my sample migraitons:

```
  @Override
    public void onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        super.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "DB_OLD_VERSION : " + 1 + ", DB_NEW_VERSION : " + 2);
            UserDao.createTable(db, false);

        } else if (oldVersion < 3) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "DB_OLD_VERSION : " + 2 + ", DB_NEW_VERSION : " + 3);

        } else if (oldVersion < 4) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "DB_OLD_VERSION : " + 3 + ", DB_NEW_VERSION : " + 4);
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + UserDao.TABLENAME + " ADD COLUMN 'uuid' TEXT;");
        } else if (oldVersion < 5) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What if the App is in production, should we notify all user to uninstall and install the app?! ))